# How do I initialize object vals with values known only at runtime?

Tags: scala

Let's say I'm trying to write a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game. It has an M x N field. The game has only one field, so it probably should be represented with a singleton `object`. Like this:

```
object Field {
    val height : Int = 20
    val width : Int = 15
    ...
}
```

But I don't want to hardcode the height and width, so it would be nice if those could be passed to the object at runtime, via a constructor or something. But `object`s cannot have constructors.

Well, I could change `height` and `width` to be `var`s, and not `val`s and introduce a new method

```
def reconfigure (h:Int, w:Int) = {
    height = h
    width = w
}
```

and call it at the begining of the game. But it's not elegant as well.

So, is there a neat way of doing this - i.e. having object `val`s initialized with values not known before runtime?

Comment: It seems any solution is going to require a `var` somewhere. Did you consider making `Field` a class with height and width constructor parameters?

Comment: @KiptonBarros I did. But i need only a single instance of that class. So I thought it would be _ideologically_ better to use `object`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not use a `class` and initialize one instance in `main`?

```
case class Field(width: Int, height: Int) {
  //...
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val field = Field(30, 25)
  }
}
```

Comment: Because it's not elegant. `object`s must be introduced in Scala for a reason. Or else, why would people use objects at all?

Comment: @Saptamus Only because the singleton pattern is called a design pattern doesn't mean it's elegant and you should use it. I'm using objects and I would not use them for your use case.

Comment: Using class is definitely de way to go. @SaptamusPrime Not sure why you say it's not elegant. The situation you describe is a standard use case in OO architecture. You are trying to force the use of Object in a situation where it does not fit. Objects are meant to be used as companions for a class, to hold the stuff common to all instances like the static part of a class in Java. That's why they're called "companion objects".

Comment: @SaptamusPrime: Looks perfectly elegant to me.

Comment: @SaptamusPrime: Singleton objects are very useful. This is not one of their use cases.

Comment: @SaptamusPrime "Elegance is a synonym for beauty that has come to acquire the additional connotations of unusual effectiveness and simplicity" - Wikipedia. Using a class is elegant if anything, especially in comparison to the accepted answer. Scala code needn't to be overengineered, in fact it can be very simple and elegant, neither singleton design pattern nor lazy initialisation fits here.

Comment: Objects are not necessarily meant to only be companion objects.  They are also meant to be modules. See "Modular Programming With Objects" in Programming in Scala (http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/modular-programming-using-objects.html)

Answer (score 15):

You could employ the use of lazy vals. This may make things more complex any you still need to use a var.

```
case class Config( height: Int, width: Int )
object Field {
  val defaultConfig = Config( 20, 15 )
  var config: Option[Config] = None
  def getConfig = config.getOrElse( defaultConfig )
  lazy val height = getConfig.height
  lazy val width = getConfig.width
}
object Main extends App {
  Field.config = Some( Config( 30, 25 ) )
}
```

Comment: I think, I get the idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One option is lazy vals:

```
object Field {
  lazy val height = // code to find height
  lazy val width = // code to find width
}
```

The val will be initialised the first time it's used, so as long as you don't use them until you have all the information you need to initialise them, you should be good.

Comment: but that's still doesn't provide the way to set this fields from the outside

Comment: This answer is crap ... Objects are initialized lazily anyway

Comment: i feel this doesn't answer to the question.

Comment: Objects are initialized lazily anyway